# PHP Send Email, HOST Address not Match Domain Address detected as spam mail

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, smtp-auth

I am having some problem on sending email through my company's website.

My company is using an Exchange Server for mailing.

Therefore, the email sent from my website HOST address not match the DOMAIN address and yahoo detected my mail as a spam or some mail service blocked and rejected.

> Received-SPF: none (domain of xxxxx.com does not designate permitted
>   sender hosts)

Php Mailer return the following:

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) SMTP
>   connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

i would like to prevent spam and able to send email through SMTP authentication, what can i do in this situation,? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run your domain through [this](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html), and fix everything that's wrong or missing. In PHPMailer, set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`, to see why your rejections are happening, and read the other advice in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

You have to configura SPF and DKIM at your server.

You need to configure SMTP credentials at phpmailer.